# Remote connection / SSH'ing into a deployed AWS AppRunner container

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate, amazon-app-runner

Is it possible to gain access to the container shell of an app I have deployed within AWS AppRunner?
I realise the service is designed to be very AWS managed, however the utility of being able to see inside your deployed container is often invaluable.
Docs I've looked at don't seem to show any sign of this being possible natively.

The other option I can think of is installing SSH tooling into the container, and exposing the SSH port to then allow connecting to the container, but this does not seem like the way AppRunner was intended to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is "no" but I'm new to App Runner so I could be wrong.